# xsd schema for my ConfigurationSection

Tags: .net, xsd, web-config, app-config

I'm developing a class library project which has it's own implementation of ConfigurationSection class. I want to provide intellisense support for configuration files. I created a valid xsd file for config section. Now the problem I have is, how to tell web.config/app.config file to use my xsd schema? I know setting xmlns attribute to the section, but this solution throws exception runtime. So is there any other way to assign configuration file my xsd schema?

And just to clear things, I will mark the correct answer and vote up the post :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your schema to the **DotNetConfig.xsd** usually located at **\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio xxx\Xml\Schemas**

**Do make a backup of the original before you proceed.**

Now you'll basically just add the elements that represent your custom config stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but the correct answer hasn't been posted yet. There's no need to modify the **DotNetConfig.xsd** file.

If you right click on the config file (either in the editor or in Solution Explorer) and go to Properties, in the **Properties** window there's a property called `Schemas`.

[image: Properties window]

If you click the "..." in the value field, the **XML Schemas** editor window will pop up and you can add your custom .xsd schema document here. Just make sure to check the "Use" column to use your xsd with that document.

[image: XML Schemas window]